# Doxywizard error : There is not enough memory available for this task

Tags: out-of-memory, doxygen, chm, doxywizard, html-help

Though I have enough memory(RAM -> ~3.5 GB and Hard Disk - > 60 GB)
I am still getting this error again and again while creating chm file using DoxyWizard.
Is there any setting I need to do to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Even if I do this from the html help compiler from the command prompt using command `hhc <index.hhp>` inside the html folder I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember, HTMLHelp (CHM's) is nearly 20 years old  and Microsoft's Windows based  help system is in "maintenance mode" only. No new features and support are expected. As far as I know there is no new help systems being developed at Microsoft.

So, the CHM Compiler (written in C++ 1996 by Ralph Walden) has some limits - it's a HH compiler problem not a Doxygen error.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/330418/file-size-limits-for-chm-html-help-format-files

Please try to compile without 'Index', try to reduce the number of topics, try to compile on a single PC (I think you are working in a server Environment).

I see a small chance for a solution only because there are about 1106 files in your snap above.

Comment: One could try the FPC CHM help compiler (chmcmd). It is used by some *nix projects.